# How to upsample audio with digital interpolation

Tags: ios, audio, signal-processing, core-audio, vdsp

I want to take an array with N number of audio data points and upsample it such that there are L*N points. I understand an accurate way to do this is to pad L-1 zero points between each original point and then to low pass the signal. According to this 4 minute video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJslC6TuCoc I should lowpass at a frequency of Pi / L and then add a gain of L to the result to properly upsample my signal. I am having trouble with this low passing step and my result audio signal is not audible at all. Can anyone help me here? Is this "low pass" really more like a band reject filter or something?

My low pass algorithm is noted here (biquad transfer function with coefficients marked under "LPF"): http://music.columbia.edu/pipermail/music-dsp/1998-October/054185.html

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate all the added points using a high quality interpolation algorithm, such as a polyphase windowed Sinc FIR filter.

Comment: Could you elaborate? This leads me on a google quest down a deep rabbit hole that I know very little about.